# Binding isn't working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is wrong here?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39xA9/).

```
function SecondCtrl($scope, Data) {
  $scope.data = Data;

  $scope.reversedMessage = function(message) {
    return message.split("").reverse().join("");
  };
}
```

Comment: you are missing many steps... like there is no module created... the controller is not added to the module... there is no provider for `Data`

Comment: a simple sample with a hard coded data http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mH5uH/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Arun mentioned in his comment, you're missing several key elements here:

1. You're not bootstrapping your app. You'll need to use either [the `ng-app` directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angApp) or [`angular.bootstrap`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap).
2. Since you're defining `SecondCtrl` as a global function (which isn't a best practice), you need to set JSFiddle to load your JavaScript before `onLoad`; I used `No wrap - in <head>`:

   [image: screenshot]
3. You're injecting `Data` into your controller, but you haven't defined `Data` as a service. You'll need to [create a service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) for this.

Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates how things might look if you follow best practices and create a module for your controller in addition to fixing the other issues: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/TcPGT/

```html
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
    <h1>{{ reversedMessage(data.message) }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

```javascript
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.value('Data', {
  message: 'This is my message.'
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, Data) {
  $scope.data = Data;

  $scope.reversedMessage = function(message) {
    return message.split("").reverse().join("");
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code i think is incomplete..Iam Attaching a complete code here..Go through it and i hope this is what your looking for.

Visit :http://plnkr.co/edit/HxScwWRT9nnaA5CILE6f?p=preview